# Opening a Pdf document in Adobe photoshop

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have a silverlight control to upload documents in my web page to share point. While I upload a document it is successfully uploaded. But when i try to open it by clicking on the document the pdf document uploaded opens in the redirected IE page.
I want that Pdf to be directly opened in Adobe Reader instead of redirecting it to open in an IE page.

Can anyone please suggest if this is a browser setting or I need some code for it?

Thanks
Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    OBJ.Save(Response.OutputStream, File);
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="

    + "abcd".ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Above is the code for downloading it. If you are saving the file in DB then get the binary data or if you are saving it in a folder within your app, give the path.